# How does a Module call a custom layout in Magento? What are pre-requirements for creating a module?

Tags: magento-1.7

In Magento, how does a Module call a custom layout file? What are the pre-requirements for creating a module?

Comment: Read this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-4-magento-layouts-blocks-and-templates. Maybe it helps. Actually you can start from here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento and read each section.

Answer (score 3):

You have to indicate the area where the layout file should be loaded, that is `adminhtml` or `frontend`. Of coure you can also add a layout file to both areas.
The configuration XML syntax is the same besides the area code.

```
<frontend><!-- or <adminhtml> -->
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <your_module>
                <file>your/module.xml</file>
            </your_module>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

Then create your layout XML file *app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/your/module.xml*.

If you are adding a layout file to the `adminhtml` area, it is customary to create it in *app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/your/module.xml* (even though the base/default theme would also work in there).

Once you have refreshed (or deactivated) the layout cache, your modules layout file will be merged together with the rest.